# How to find rows in mySQL DB which have no duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
--id---name---col1--col2--col3...-colN--created. 
--1---myName---col1--col2--col3...-colN--created1. 
--2---myName---col1--col2--col3...-colN--created2. 
--3---myOtherName---Othercol1--Othercol2--Othercol3...-OthercolN--created3.
```

`id` and `created` fields are unique.

Rest of the rows has duplicates - exact the same set of values (name+col1+col2+col3+..+colN).

However, few rows are completely unique. **How could I find them** (`row 3` in my example)?

Comment: Not able to get you where you stuck. As you say you have two unique column then you should use these two column only to fetch required row.

Comment: @Kandy, I know only: --id---name---col1--col2--col3...-colN--created.

Comment: @Kandy, so I have to find "myOtherName" as it is unique.

Comment: As you say Myname-col1-----colLn it may contains duplicate than how it will unique and also if you have id and creted3 column is unique than it will always return one row

Comment: @Kandy, I have had an example of 3 rows. You can see that 2 of them are completely unique (except of id and created) - so I wasn't interested in them. But third rows is unique, so I was trying to find it in full rows list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery selecting rows from the same table with a different ID but equal values.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM elbat t2
                                WHERE t2.id <> t1.id
                                      AND t2.col1 = t1.col1
                                      AND t2.col2 = t1.col2
                                      AND t2.col3 = t1.col3
                                      ...
                                      AND t2.coln = t1.coln);
```

Comment: Looks that it is exact what I was looking for. Thank you for your support! Wish you good luck in all of your projects!

Answer (score 1):

You can group by fields that must be unique and then select rows where the count equals to one.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  mytable
  INNER JOIN (
               SELECT id
               FROM
                 mytable
               GROUP BY
                 col1, col2, col3
               HAVING
                 COUNT(*) = 1
             ) t
    ON mytable.id = t.id;
```

There are a number of solutions. Depending on the amount of data and performance requirements you could add indexes and test a couple of solutions to get the optimal results.

Comment: Thank you for your support!